# Can I map an array of types to another array of types in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I want to make a class to wrap some primitive types into another such as:

```
class MyClass<T> {
    foo? : T
}

type Input = [string, number, boolean]

type Remap<T> = MyClass<T>

type Output = Remap<Input>  // <-- Now it's MyClass<Input>
// Can I make the Remap to infer an Output as the following?
// type Output = [MyClass<string>, MyClass<number>, MyClass<boolean>]
```

But I don't know how to, if doable, make a proper Remap type to make the Output match my expection.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WJrxlW)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in fact this can be done with a plain [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html):

```
type Remap<T> = { [I in keyof T]: MyClass<T[I]> }

type Output = Remap<Input>
//   ^? type Output = [MyClass<string>, MyClass<number>, MyClass<boolean>]
```

Mapped types that act on `keyof T` where `T` is a generic type parameter automatically [transform arrays to arrays and tuples to tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays).

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhcUA8AVAfNA3gKGkOgDMB7UgfgC5p08BfPPAF3gAcBTaASQDs2Ars2gBeaAG0IzAE4BLXgHMANNF4CAtgCMO0lZvIgOYXgF0mrTtABKHdWDYZsYnBO7R50ANYd4pYrRMaBGRICAxxbhNsRhZ2LgB5IUFhMRs7Bz5kzDwAehyiAD0KPCA)

Comment: Never thought the solution would be such simply. My mind must be lost in somewhere :p

Comment: In fact the curly brace was confusing me. Once I saw it I would consider the output would be a form in Object type and never thought it would also produce an Array type.

Answer (score 1):

### Updated solution

Thanks for jcalz for mentioning this much simpler approach in a comment. I've left my prior solution below.

You can use a mapped type to modify a tuple type, just like when modifying an object type. For example:

```js
class MyClass<T> {
    foo? : T
}

type Input = [string, number, boolean]

type RemapTuple<T extends unknown[]> = {
    [K in keyof T]: MyClass<T[K]>;
};

type Output = RemapTuple<Input>  // <-- [MyClass<string>, MyClass<number>, MyClass<boolean>]
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhcUA8AVAfNA3gKGkOgDMB7UgfmgC5p08BfPPAF3gAcBTaASQDt2AVxbQAvNADaEFgCcAlnwDmAGmh9BAWwBGnGaq3kQnMHwC6zNl2gAlThrDt0g9kYzROADxac+AExiCfADWfKQA7nwSptji+ESSANLQCtBBnPCkxHSmtAjIkBAYEgnRANyM5awc3ADywkIi4rb2js6u-A3Y0AD03dCoALQDknkohdLySpiqowWo6tq603BIY6gGpEYmmOZAA)

---

### Previous solution

You can use recursive type inference to map each element of a tuple type, like your `Input` type in this example, to create a new tuple with each element having been mapped in a particular way.

Each step of recursion maps the initial element, and then re-runs the recursive utility type over the tuple type constructed from any remaining elements. And they all get combined back together into a new tuple type at the end.

Here's an example of how you could implement a type like that:

```js
class MyClass<T> {
    foo? : T
}

type Input = [string, number, boolean]

type RemapTuple<T extends unknown[]> = T extends [infer A, ...infer B] ? [MyClass<A>, ...RemapTuple<B>] : T;

type Output = RemapTuple<Input>  // <-- [MyClass<string>, MyClass<number>, MyClass<boolean>]
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhcUA8AVAfNA3gKGkOgDMB7UgfmgC5p08BfPPAF3gAcBTaASQDt2AVxbQAvNADaEFgCcAlnwDmAGmh9BAWwBGnGaq3kQnMHwC6zNl2gAlThrDt0g9kYzROADxac+AExiCfADWfKQA7nwSptji6O5ePv6SCsS60ACCqgB0OSlpAEKm0FQSCMiQEKjpmNk5tvaOzq75mEW06ADcFhzcAPLCQiLi9Q5OLpyo-IPY0AD0s9CoALRLkmUoldLySjVwSBuo6tq6u+sVqAakRiateEA)

Comment: Uhhh is there a reason you're resorting to recursion here instead of just doing a plain mapped type?

Comment: No, it's just the only solution I could think of. Did I miss something simpler or more obvious?

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. Honestly, it didn't even occur to me that a mapped type would work with tuples. I'll update my answer to reflect that much better solution, thanks for mentioning it